# C: UDP send & receive packets

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I've been trying to use the socket() api in C but no luck so far.
I would like to send a request to a specific device (Address: 192.168.2.55 Port: 12850) which will then return data to the application. How do I do this in C. I'm on a Mac so "the Unix way" if that differs from Windows...

Thanks and merry christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps involved in establishing a socket on the client side are as follows:

1. Create a socket with the socket() system call
2. Connect the socket to the address of the server using the connect() system call
3. Send and receive data. There are a number of ways to do this, but the simplest is to use the read() and write() system calls.

The steps involved in establishing a socket on the server side are as follows:

1. Create a socket with the socket() system call
2. Bind the socket to an address using the bind() system call. For a server socket on the Internet, an address consists of a port number on the host machine.
3. Listen for connections with the listen() system call
4. Accept a connection with the accept() system call. This call typically blocks until a client connects with the server.
5. Send and receive data

Check to see if you have followed these steps thusfar with the code you have written.

Comment: could you post / link to some example code.. I'm fairly new to C and don't really know how to handle the socket api, sry..

Comment: @JNK - sure thing, I should have included this url to begin with http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Answer (score 2):

For socket programming introduction, see http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: @user502515 Thx for the link… I already  read some parts of it but I'm still not quite sure how to put everything together…